# How to get the decimal number from ASCII code in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, ascii, mips

I want to read a character and I'm using bascially this code:

```
main:
li   $v0, 12       
syscall         

li $v0, 10
syscall
```

So, the ASCII code is saved in $v0 as a HEX number, but is there some way to get this correspondent ASCII code in decimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hex is a text serialization format for binary integers.  The value in `$v0` is a 32-bit binary number, not hex or decimal.

e.g. `32` (decimal) and `0x20` (hex) are two ways to describe the value of the same bit pattern (`0b0000...00100000`).  All of these are different ways to express the ASCII code for a space, like you'd get from `li $v0, ' '`.

You can view it as hex or as decimal using your debugger, or using different MARS print-number system calls if you're running your MIPS code on the MARS emulator.  (SPIM only has a `print integer` system call, but MARS has ones for print in hex, print in decimal, and print in binary. http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html)

```
move  $a0, $v0     # $a0 = integer to print 
li    $v0, 1       # $v0 = system-call number
syscall            # print_integer($a0)  in decimal
```